# Send textfile over socket using writer/reader?

Tags: java

Is there a way to send a textfile from client to server using XXXwriter and XXXreader instead of sending bytes? 
Any suggestions?

Comment: Look at `InputStreamReader` and `OutputStreamWriter`.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. A textfile is just bytes. What else do you want to send? You can use OutputStreamWriter and InputStreamReader if you have problems with Input/OutputStreams and prefer the Writers.

Comment: I'm using inputstream and outputstream now, and the program is not working as I want it to. Therefore I'm thinking about trying writer/reader instead when sending and receiving the textfile, but I'm not sure if it is possible?

Comment: Maybe you should be asking why your program doesn't work, if you want to know why it doesn't work...

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use a reader/writer. You should fix your code instead.

Comment: Instead of asking how to do this with a `Reader` and `Writer`, explain your current program and explain in detail in what way it is not working as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the InputStream in an InputStreamReader, and the OutputStream in an OutputStreamWriter. These classes bridge binary (`byte[], *Stream`) from/to java's Unicode text (String, char, *Reader, *Writer). Use the constructor with the correct encoding.

```
Charset encoding = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
String encoding = "Windows-1252";
... new InputStreamReader(inputStream, encoding);
```

This however assumes that the Stream transfer is done fine. Possible errors are:

- forgetting to `close`, not all data transfered;
- use of `available()` which is not needed;
- using a buffer to `read`, and not writing the actual number of bytes read, old data at the end.